# Use data's user on different pages

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone

I'm doing an application. Based on mvvm, my app has different pages:
Inscription
Connection
Profil
...
I would like to transfert my user's info from page to page so i'm using

```
this.Client_ = (Client)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Client"];
```

But i'm not sure that it's the best idea to have my user's info. To get some info like photo, personal information like mail or adress i will call the server. Here I'm talking about the informations that i need for the server to get the correct user's info like pseudo and password. What is the best option to pass information from page to page ?

Thanks a lot for responding, sorry for english mistakes i could have done, je ne suis pas anglais ;).

Answer (score 0):

Use a constants class and have a static member. You would be able to access that from anywhere. (same is the case with declaring something in App.xaml.cs but it is not recommended overloading the app.xaml.cs class)

rough example:

```
public class AppConstants
{
     public static string Username = string.Empty;
     public static Image userImage;
}
```

while navigating from page A to page B, you can set those parameters in page A

```
AppConstants.Username = "Abhiram";
AppConstants.Image = Obj_ClassA;
```

In Page B you can access these. 
    userName = AppConstants.Username;
    ObjClassB = AppConstants.Image;

This would avoid your I/O and read-write operations in StorageSettings. This is a basic Global variable approach.

Please mark this as an answer if it helps.